# Работа с БД в Си

Tags: c, postgresql

создал двунаправленный список в СИ, создал в Postgre SQL базу данных из нескольких таблиц - как работать с базой данныx через си? (Переписать данные в список, удалить из БД стоку).

Подскажите какое-то апи или способ что-бы создать соединение(использую Visual Studio).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если хотите использовать API самого PostgreSQL, используйте libpq. вот ссылка на документацию [тыц](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/libpq). все методы описаны на русском, так что разобраться не должно составить труда. сама библиотека лежит в директории bin вашей postgresql.
либо вот, специальный инструмент для visual studio [тыц](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/)